# Why is the operation of this latching circuit using a momentary switch and a D-flip flop inconsistent?

Tags: circuit-design, switches, flipflop

I'm trying to make a toggle circuit that uses a momentary switch and D-flipflop to toggle an LED on and off.

Here is what I have breadboarded, and the logic table for the flipflop. Both resistors are 330 ohms. Vcc = 3.3V:

[image]

[image]

The circuit works, though its operation is inconsistent. Sometimes a single press will toggle, and other times it needs X number of presses to toggle. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you have a part number and link to a datasheet for the flip flop?  What value is the resistor on the left?

Comment: @evildemonic the resistor value is 330 ohms https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/atqnt9l95g/PHGLS25117-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw

Comment: What voltage is your supply?

Comment: @evildemonic both resistors are 330ohms, and Vcc is 3.3V

Comment: Is D really floating, or do you have it tied high or low?

Comment: If the D input is floating you are just sampling noise. Not to mention that the switch contacts bounce so you probably sample the noise many times.

Comment: The D input is floating, what should it be tied to?

Comment: @evildemonic the D input is floating.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with the circuit:  1) the switch needs de-bouncing;  2) The D input is not connected.

1. When you press a switch, the contacts do not come together cleanly.  they bounce against each other under the pressure of the armature spring.  Depending on the switch, there can be dozens of make-break-make-breaks in a few milliseconds.

For a SPST momentary switch, the most common way to "de-bounce" the signal is to add a capacitor in parallel with the pull-down resistor.  Start with an R-C time constant of around 50 ms.  If the erratic behavior decreases but doesn't stop, increase the time constant to 100 ms and test again.

Unless you are using an old, standard TTL device, 330 ohms is a very low value for a pull-down resistor.  For a CMOS part, start with something like 10K, and 4.7 uF for the debounce capacitor.If there still  is bouncing going on, increase either the resistor to 20 K or the capacitor to 10 uF.

2. For toggle action, the schematic is incorrect.  As in other answers, it is incomplete.  There needs to be a direct connection between the Q- output and the D input.  If needed, the Q- output still can be used to drive downstream circuits.

Note: a discussion like this goes *much* better if you assign a unique reference designator to each component in the schematic.

Answer (score 0):

The input at D appears at the outputs Q and, in your case, *Q on the rising edge of the clock input.  If D is not connected to anything, then noise on the input will cause the output to take on a more or less random value.  As others have mentioned, the switch contact bounce will cause multiple clock inputs to the flip-flop.  To get toggle action, you should connect *Q to D and debounce the clock input.